# Getting PHP Error on upgrade from 3.0.36 to 3.1

Tags: php, error-message, upgrades

I just updated to 3.1 and I'm getting the php error:

PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException

Undefined index: settings

It probably has to do with the Cheat Sheet plugin.  I deleted that folder in the vendor directly but no luck.

I can send along the link showing the errors.

Thank you!

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?

Comment: Did you try to rename the original vendor folder to say vendor-old and do a composer install ?

Answer (score 1):

If you restore from a 3.0.36 database backup, then update to the latest Craft 3.1 release (currently [3.1.2.2](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#3122---2019-01-19), this shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a backup for the database at this point.  Any other options before I blow this up and start over?  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah... nothing comes to mind without being able to restore the database, unfortunately.